# ASP.net application unable to connect to SQL Server named instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, connection, connection-string

We have an application that is out side the firewall, for connecting to the database we have a opened a port. I am able to connect to the database from my visual studio but I am not able to connect from my prod site which is out side the firewall

```
<add name="PRODConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=IPAddress\SQL2008,58124;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=user_id;Password=password"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Above is the connection string i am using currently

Can any one please help me with this.

Thanks,
Avinash

Comment: For testing can you create a text file, rename it with a `UDL` extension and give us the error message you get when you try to connect?

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

Comment: is there something wrong with my connection string? can it resolve the instance name SQL2008?

Comment: There's little doubt that something is wrong with either the connection string or the connectivity between your source computer and the production database. There are myriad possibilities: Incorrect/different port configured for SQL Server, firewall blocking inbound connections on the server, proxy server between networks, to name only a few. Very hard to diagnose further without more detail that's hard to come by in this format. Glad to help, but pls understand this kind of issue can be hard to diagnose here.

Comment: Thanks I will let you know if I find anything

Comment: Did you find out anything? just curious

Answer (score 0):

If the user account(ID) is a windows account make sure you are doing this:

```
ID=ServerName\user_id
```

Comment: it is sql server account it is working fine if i connect from my local it just does not work from prod.

Comment: I take it you have checked the production servers windows firewall?

Comment: Yes I did check to make sure its opened

Comment: Data Source=IPAddress\SQL2008,58124 should there be a common there? That the only thing I see that throws me off of a server name.

Comment: server name is ipaddress\namedinstance which is ip\sql2008

Comment: This link here might help you http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/09/sql-server-fix-error-1326-cannot-connect-to-database-server-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting through a firewall, and resolving the server via its IP address, are you sure that TCP has been enabled as one of the transports on SQL Server, and that the proper ports have been opened on the firewall?

Comment: it is enabled i am using the same connection string from my visual studio and it works fine. it does not work on prod site

Comment: You are resolving the local reference (the one that works) via IP address?

Comment: yes i can access the application from my local machine with the same connection string i am using from my prod

Comment: Well, unless your server admins have purposely changed the default port on your SQL server, it should be listening on port 1433, not 58124

Comment: If you have a clean network path to the SQL Server, can you open a command prompt on your box and ping its IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have firewall on the application side as well?
Maybe you have blocked the incoming sql connection on the application side?

Or maybe you have the internal IP address as opposed to the public IP?

I'm just trying to think of reasons why the connection could be failing.

Or try this connectionstring: Added "Network Library=DBMSSOCN"

```
<add name="PRODConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=IPAddress\SQL2008,58124;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=user_id;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The added string, specifies the protocol to be [TCP/IP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28VS.71%29.aspx).